# Google Maps Speed Limit

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm trying to create a speed limit guide app (city-wide coverage). I've been researching and I found out that to access speed limit data in Google Maps API, you need to subscribe to a premium plan and access the speed limit data via Roads API. I'm just wondering if there are other ways to do a speed limit app that automatically adjusts depending on where the user is currently? Maybe hard code that if the user is somewhere between these 2 points on the road, its speed limit is etc. or an alternative map, I'm not really sure.

Hoping for your kind response, thanks.

Comment: The problem is the amount of data.  Where would you get it?  How would you keep it up to date?  ITs a massive undertaking that cost Google millions of dollars and requires them to spend more to keep it updated.  That's why they charge for it.  It's not practical for a person or small company to do the same.

Comment: Hello @GabeSechan, there's an image of a map that the city government provided for speed limits in highways, and other than that (streets) it's considered fixed 30 kph. But I still cannot fathom how I will be able to integrate it in Google Maps. I understand your opinion completely and maybe this is really a long shot.